# Is there any documentation anywhere on how to programmatically configure logback?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I've seen several questions here on StackOverFlow, and some comments about it in the user documentation of Logback, but I cant' seem to find any concrete documentation on how to programmatically configure logback. All I can find are some examples for specific cases, nothing in general that would help overall.

Comment: Did you look at all the information at the [LogBack website](http://logback.qos.ch/)?

Comment: Yes I did and couldn't find any. Especially the configuration section. It says you can do it programmatically but there's nothing in terms of actual examples or documentation: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html In fact none of the chapters show any information on how to do it other than saying you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no documentation on the website. Until I'm proven wrong or the documentation is updated I unfortunately have to go with this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the test cases involving appenders.

Comment: Are you talking about the unit tests? I actually did and there wasn't much other than the very basic on how to create them. No real information on how to config logback/slf4j

Answer (score 0):

Logback can be configured programmatically with Joran. The Logback documentation has [an entire chapter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html) on using Joran.

Another way is [using Spring](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring).